How to Invoke a Modal Dialog Popup with Image/Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams Using BotBuilder for Node.js?
Title: How to Invoke a Modal Dialog Popup with Image/Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams Using BotBuilder for Node.js?
Body:
Hi everyone,
I'm working on a project where I'm building a chatbot using the BotBuilder library for Node.js and Express and integrating it with Microsoft Teams. I'm trying to implement a feature where the bot can invoke a modal dialog popup containing an image or an Adaptive Card when a certain action occurs in the conversation.
I've been looking through the BotBuilder documentation and various resources online, but I haven't been able to find a clear example or explanation of how to achieve this specific functionality.
Could someone provide guidance or resources on how to implement this feature using BotBuilder for Node.js and Express? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding:
How to trigger the modal dialog popup from the bot in response to a user action or message.
How to structure the content of the modal dialog, particularly if I want to include an image or an Adaptive Card.
Any additional configuration or setup required within the Microsoft Teams environment to enable this functionality.
Any examples, code snippets, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
I have tried to send an invoke activity
through the bot builder send activity api
but it says Bad argument unknown activity type
Code for Reference -
using this payload to send an initial invoke request as per the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=dotnet
{
  "type": "invoke",
  "id": "f:bc319b1d-571a-194d-9ffb-11d7ab37c9ff",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1aBjVi5MwCFfhPIV03E5uDdfpBFXp_2Yz-sjrvVg12oavg96cqpE_DiMhOpmN9zHeZpYbJcuUEKuSDy2AYWPz1A",
    "name": "Olo Brockhouse",
    "aadObjectId": "b130c271-d2eb-45f9-83ab-9eb3fe3788bc"
  }
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "0d9b645f-597b-41f0-a2a3-ef103fbd91bb"
    },
    "source": {
      "name": "compose"
    }
  },
  "value": {
    "commandId": "Test",
    "commandContext": "compose",
    "requestId": "fe50f49e5c74440bb2ebf07f49e9553c",
    "context": {
      "theme": "default"
    }
  },
  "name": "composeExtension/fetchTask"

please see the attached images for reference
enter image description here

please share the code in the above question . Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I followed this document to create a bot app in Microsoft Teams using JavaScript.
Create a Bot App Project:

Install Teams Toolkit, Microsoft Teams, Node.js, and Visual Studio Code.
Launch Visual Studio Code and click on the Teams Toolkit icon in the Visual Studio Code activity bar. Then, click on Create a New App.

Choose Bot as the app feature that you want to create, and select JavaScript as the programming language.

Choose the default or a specific location to save your project, provide a name for your app, and create it.

Select F5 in Visual Studio Code to build and run your app.

Select the Teams Toolkit icon in Visual Studio Code, select Sign in to M365, and provide your Microsoft 365 account credentials.

I followed this doc for Templating SDKs Adaptive Cards and for Designer Adaptive Cards.

I used this doc for Adaptive card popup.


The code below implements a popup modal with an Adaptive Card using the "adaptivecards" library and code taken from git.
 const templatePayload = {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.3",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": `Hello ${data.name}!`
                },
                {
                    "type": "Image",
                    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/300",  // Image URL
                    "altText": "Sample Image"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "This is a sample Adaptive Card modal dialog."
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "Learn More",
                    "url": "https://adaptivecards.io/"
                }
            ]
        };

        // Create an Adaptive Card instance from the payload
        const template = new ACData.Template(templatePayload);

        // Create the Adaptive Card with the provided data
        const adaptiveCardPayload = template.expand({ $root: data });

        // Send the invoke activity to display the modal dialog
        await context.sendActivity({
            type: "invoke",
            name: "taskModule",
            value: {
                title: "Adaptive Card Modal Dialog",
                height: "medium",
                width: "medium",
                card: adaptiveCardPayload
            }
        });
    }
}



